# Where do I put my redirect or return_template

Tags: python, post, flask

In my flask app, you start on a page where you click a few buttons to tally item names, prices and quantities of items.  With the below JS i make a post request to the webserver with that data:

```
$(document).on('click',".order_submit", function() {

     prodJSON = JSON.stringify(prodData)
     console.log(prodJSON)

        $.ajax({
            url: "/load_ajax",
            type: 'POST',
            data: prodJSON,
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        });

});
```

What I want from the flask code below is to start on home.html, then when you submit your order, you are brought to the thankyou.html page.  I know the POST request is working in the load_ajax function, but for some reason on order submit, the page does not change.  How do i get it to redirect after an order submit?

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def pos_page():
        return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/load_ajax', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load_ajax():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        print list(data)
        return render_template('thankyou.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get redirect the browser page from an AJAX response; you'll have to handle this in your AJAX  handler, explictly:

```
$(document).on('click',".order_submit", function() {

    prodJSON = JSON.stringify(prodData)
    console.log(prodJSON)

    $.ajax({
        url: "/load_ajax",
        type: 'POST',
        data: prodJSON,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            document.location = data['location'];
        }
    });
});
```

This expects a JSON response with a `location` key; you can then tell the AJAX handler to redirect (with using [`flask.jsonify()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.json.jsonify) to produce the response):

```
from flask import jsonify


@app.route('/load_ajax', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load_ajax():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        print list(data)
        return jsonify(location=url_for('thankyou'))

@app.route('/thankyou')
def thankyou():
    return render_template('thankyou.html')
```

So the `load_ajax()` tells the handler the location to redirect to, and the `thankyou.html` page is served by a separate route.

Comment: Would having `success : "{{ url_for('thankyou') }}"` in the AJAX call and defining a view method and route for `/thankyou` work?

Comment: @shaktimaan: that's what my answer *does*. :-) Note the `jsonify()` response.

Comment: @shaktimaan i had tried something like this but i think i was having problems with the jinja templating being in a separate js file.  it was trying to redirect to the url of `{{ url_for('thankyou') }}`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not sure why this is needed `document.location = data['location']` then?

Comment: @shaktimaan: the AJAX `success` function receives the JSON data, then needs to act on that. Telling the browser to load a new URL from JavaScript requires setting `document.location`.

Comment: @Barnaby: You are not executing a template here but producing JSON instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you were to start from scratch is there a different way to approach this?? like can all of the redirection be done in flask or does alot of it have to do with the ajax?

Comment: @Barnaby: what is it you are trying to do here? What does the button click *mean*? You can make it a form POST instead for example. Add a `<form>` tag, hidden fields, then use jQuery to submit that form. That's a browser location change instead of an asynchonous AJAX request.